# getting ASCII value for a character represented in String format in java

Tags: java, string, character

I have an use case wherein I want to get the ASCII value for characters represented in String format. For example: I have string variable charString="'\0'". So I wanted the ASCII value for the character '\0' i.e 0

String charString = "'\0'";

Kindly let me know how this can be acheived in Java

Comment: Use `charAt` and cast to `int`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```
String charString = "'\0'";
int i = charString.charAt(0); // == 0
```

This works for all characters < 65536, not just ASCII ones.

Comment: <p>Not exactly! I wanted the ascii value for '\0' but '\0' is not store as character but as string.</p> String charString = "'\0'"; int i = charString.charAt(0); // This would return ASCII of ' (single quote i.e. 39)

Comment: @Paranthaman In that case you need to decode the string yourself as there is no standard function to do this.  If there is a name for this format you could search for it, but I suspect this is a unique requirement so you will have to write the code yourself.